# How i make table inside table in html?

Tags: html, css

i make the table but there's an error while making table inside table. So my question is that how i can insert table inside another table?

[image: i wanna to show my table like that]

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mcve]. First read a tutorial about how tables work, then try to code and, if you get stuck aske here.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the idea with this nested table example...

```
   <html>
    <body >
      <table border=5 bordercolor=red>
        <tr>
          <td>
            First Column of Outer Table
          </td>
          <td>
            <table border=5 bordercolor=green>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  First row of Inner Table
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  Second row of Inner Table
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </td>
      </tr>
      </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Hope it works for you...

Comment: To reproduce the OP images they don't need nested table

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your picture, you do not need a table inside of a table. Instead, what you need to do is use `rowspan` and `colspan` attributes on your `th`/`td` elements in your table.

[W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_table_colspan_rowspan.asp) has a good guide on how to use them. I have also attached a sample down below as an example for you to help get you started

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th colspan=2>People</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <td>Jill</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th rowspan="2">Phone</th>
    <td>555-1234</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>555-8745</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `colspan` and `rowspan` to archive this table style

```css
table.customTable {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-color: #7ea8f8;
  border-style: solid;
  color: #000000;
}

table.customTable td,
table.customTable th {
  border-width: 2px;
  border-color: #7ea8f8;
  border-style: solid;
  padding: 5px;
}

table.customTable thead {
  background-color: #7ea8f8;
}
```

```html
<table class="customTable">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2"></td>
      <td colspan="2"></td>
      <td rowspan="2"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```